# Android Apptitude practice app

Tags: android

I want to develop an aptitude app.. 
for that in my text view i have to display first question .. On clicking next button i have to display second question.. on again clicking same next button third question have to be displayed.. liked that i want to display some 30 questions ..all questions should be displayed in single java file.I Tried to display two questions . but for multiple questions i could not find the code..

```
  package com.example.asl;
  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.Random;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

  public class Aptitude extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aptitude);
    Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final String Question[]={"what is UR Name","What is ur Age","Whats ur Qualification"};
    Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     final TextView cumulos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //TextView respostas = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.respostas);

        Random randPhrase = new Random();
        final String[] cum = {"what is UR Name","What is ur Age","Whats ur Qualification"};
        //String[] resp = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.resp_cumulos);

        String textout = "";
        String textresp = "";

    //Button btnPrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourPreviousbutton);

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

         public void onClick(View arg0) {
             int i = 0;
              if(i<cum.length-1){
                   i+=1;
                   cumulos.setText(cum[i]);
                  // respostas.setText(resp[i]);
              }

         }


    });
    //btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

         //public void onClick(View arg0) {
              //if(i>0){
                  // i-=1;
                 //  cumulos.setText(cum[i]);
                  // respostas.setText(resp[i]);
             // }

        // }


    //});

}

  }

enter code here
```

Comment: Are you getting some error in this code or do you not know how to make the app? I cant understand the issue fully.

Comment: i cant change Questions ... in text view i get first ques.. after clicking button next should come.. on third click third ques should come

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializing your counter in your `onClick()` is always going to reset it

Initialize it outside of `onClick()` and increment it in `onClick()` as you are.

```
public class Aptitude extends Activity {

   int i = 0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aptitude);
        Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ...
   }

     public void onClick(View arg0) {  // rename arg0 to something meaningful 
                                       // like v or view for readibility
     //    int i = 0;   remove this guy
          if(i<cum.length-1){
               i+=1;
               cumulos.setText(cum[i]);
```

If this doesn't fix your problem then please *explain* what the problem is but I'm sure this part was causing you trouble.

Comment: i need to display a question that is set in array when i first enter that page.. after clicking button next question of that array should display replacing existing first question. on second click third ques of array should be displayed replacing second ques...

Comment: That's what I thought you were trying to do. This solution should help you on your way then.

Comment: thanks very much...
this coding works for me...but i want to do the same by retrieving from server database instead of array ...  
   
    
 public int count=0;
 
  
  
  final String Question[]={"whatsURName","WhatsurAge","WhatsurQualition"};
  tv.setText("hello");
  
  b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    
    
    count++;
    switch (count) {
    case 0:tv.setText(Question[0]);
     
     break;
    case 1:tv.setText(Question[1]) ;break;
    case 2:tv.setText(Question[2]);break;

    
    }
    
    
   }
  });
  
  
 
 }

}